# localhost wordpress won't load completely on tor browser

Tags: onion-services

[image]first , sorry for bad English

i try to run a wordpress site on local machine and everything is ok but when i brows my site using tor browser page wont load completely an when i click on a link ,[![enter image description here][2]][2] url change to http://localhost/site
what shod i do

Comment: You've misconfigured your wordpress to believe that its hostname is `localhost` rather than `[whatever].onion`, so it's likely linking to resources at "localhost" for it's css, images, etc which won't work. This has absolutely nothing to do with Tor, it's bad configuration or your wordpress on your part.

Answer (score 0):

tor browse uses noscript in default and wordpress require js so that is where it break. On second-hand wordpress is quite vulnerable so if you don't take caution you get pwned and your ip will be leaked.

Comment: there is any why to disable js wordpress? othere CMS are same?

Answer (score 0):

This can solve your problem:

1. Install "Local" tool from https://localwp.com/
2. In WordPress settings set WordPress Address (URL) to: http://youronionwebsite.onion
3. In WordPress settings set Site Address (URL) to: http://youronionwebsite.onion
4. In Local tool set Site domain and SSL to: http://youronionwebsite.onion

I think that problem is in webserver software, because all like XAMMP or WAMP running on Apache. Local works on Nginx and there works onion site on Tor from localhost perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing is not a Wordpress-specific one, it's a general problem for web applications. You have to set your *requested host name* to the onion one to comply with HTTP 1.1 or 2.0 standard. To access your web application locally use your `hosts' file to pinpoint the webserver IP, i.e. 127.0.0.1, to the onion name to avoid this mess